# Is it possible to create a class that represents another type in Python, when directly referenced?

Tags: python, class, object

So if I have a class like:

```
CustomVal
```

I want to be able to represent a literal value, so like setting it in the constructor:

```
val = CustomVal ( 5 )

val.SomeDefaultIntMethod
```

Basically I want the CustomVal to represent whatever is specified in the constructor.

I am not talking about custom methods that know how to deal with CustomVal, but rather making it another value that I need.

Is this possible?

Btw 5 is just an example, in reality it's a custom COM type that I want to instance easily.

So by referencing CustomVal, I will have access to int related functionality (for 5), or the functionality of the object that I want to represent (for COM).

So if the COM object is RasterizedImage, then I will have access to its methods directly:

```
CustomVal.Raster () ...
```

EDIT: This is what I mean: I don't want to access as an attribute, but the object itself:

```
CustomVal
```

instead of:

```
CustomVal.SomeAttribute
```

The reason I want this is because, the COM object is too involved to initialize and by doing it this way, it will look like the original internal implementation that app offers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way to wrap an object in Python is to override `__getattr__` in your class:

```
class CustomVal(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.value, attr)
```

So then you can do

```
>>> obj = CustomVal(wrapped_obj)
>>> obj.SomeAttributeOfWrappedObj
```

You can also override `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` to enable setting and deleting attributes, respectively (see [the Python library documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)).

Answer (score 2):

You just might be overthinking this... You can put anything you want into your `val`, then call whatever method of the object you want:

```
>>> val = ThingaMoBob(123, {p:3.14}, flag=False)
>>> val.SomeCrazyMathod()
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think he wants the new object to implement the exact same interface of the object he passes to its constructor. A sort of GoF-style decorator pattern...

Comment: If it implements the same interface, then -- well -- isn't it just the original object?  Why wrap it?  Just use it.

Comment: @S.Lott It is not necessarily the original object. From wikipedia: In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows new/additional behaviour to be added to an existing class dynamically. check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern